# clojure -- how to run a program without piping it's output?

Tags: shell, clojure, subprocess

I want to use something like **shell-out** [ http://richhickey.github.com/clojure-contrib/shell-out-api.html ], but without capturing the any output. Of course the output can be passed to print, but this is slightly less than desirable (e.g. in the case that the subprocess may fail).

#### edit

Sorry, I want the subprocess to output to the same `stdout` as the parent process.

Comment: Do you want to silence the subprocess ( > /dev/null ) or do you want the subprocess to use the same stdout as the parent process? In any case, you have the full range of JDK classes at your disposal.

Comment: the latter; the question has been edited.

Answer (score 5):

Also see this third party library

https://github.com/Raynes/conch

It provides direct access to the streams.

Answer (score 3):

*EDIT: Before Clarification*

You can wrap the shell command with a sh and then pipe to /dev/null like so:

```
 (clojure.java.shell/sh "sh" "-c" "echo hello > /dev/null")
 ;; {:exit 0, :out "", :err ""}
```

This will silence the output before getting to clojure.

*EDIT: After Clarification*

Passing output and stderr to print should work as long as the output comes out quickly enough. If you want something with continuous output of error messages and standard output, looking at the source for the "sh" function should help.

Personally, I would make my own version of clojure.java.shell/sh and for each stream, create a thread that pipes the output directly to *out* using something like IOUtils.copy from org.apache.commons.io.IOUtilsin

Comment: Invoking the system shell is totally non-portable.  Also, it doesn't seem this can be done using `Process.exec()`.  I guess the portable version will have to wait until Java 7's [`ProcessBuilder`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) is released.

Comment: if you don't read the output promptly enough the process could block on writes to its stdout and appear to hang. same for stderr

Comment: @Arthur, yes, and also if everything gets killed the print might not execute, and you might miss valuable debugging information from the partial output of the subprocess.